# how do i tranform my ols equation into logs?

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation, least-squares, lognormal-distribution, methodology

Hi i'm reading threw all my statistics notes and i can't find any mention of how to transform ols variables into logs. ie i can't see a equation or any method of turning a beta value into a log form.

i know why we must do this but i can't work out how. also is there a different method for partial transformations ie turning the equation prices= beat0 +betaone wages +betatwo population growth into y = beta0 plus betaone wages plus log population growth

Comment: You cannot accurately transform one such model into the other: they express different relationships among the variables altogether.  You need to re-estimate the model based on the log data.

Comment: thats what i thought but going over my econometric past papers there is a question that asks you to convert the depend variable into natural logs and then convert the independent variable into logs and finally combine the two equations by converting the whole thing into natural logs

Comment: You can certainly convert either or both the DV and the IVs into logs and then run the regression on a logged variable (provided all data are positive). You cannot directly turn a beta value into a log.

Comment: just to clarify would i have to log all individual observations or the parameter of the equation say i regressed the model and foun it to have a value of y = 56.8 +.7x1 would i have to log the x observations or just log the .71 etc

Answer (score 2):

This method will not match the estimates you get from a regression of $y$ on $\ln x$, but can be a reasonable approximation in some cases if you don't have the data. It comes from the definition of [semi-elasticity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticity_of_a_function#Semi-elasticity).

Take the estimated effect of $x$ on $y$ from the original regression (.7) and multiply that by the average value of $x$. This will give you a semi-elasticity of sorts.

Here's an example using Stata and the 1978 cars dataset where I regress mileage (in miles per gallon) on vehicle length (in inches):

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. reg mpg length 

      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =      74
-------------+------------------------------           F(  1,    72) =  124.33
       Model |  1547.35715     1  1547.35715           Prob > F      =  0.0000
    Residual |  896.102311    72  12.4458654           R-squared     =  0.6333
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.6282
       Total |  2443.45946    73  33.4720474           Root MSE      =  3.5279

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      length |  -.2067688    .018544   -11.15   0.000    -.2437355   -.1698021
       _cons |   60.15586   3.509057    17.14   0.000     53.16068    67.15104
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. sum length 

    Variable |       Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+--------------------------------------------------------
      length |        74    187.9324    22.26634        142        233

. di _b[length]*187.9324
-38.858558

. gen lnlength=ln(length)

. reg mpg lnlength 

      Source |       SS       df       MS              Number of obs =      74
-------------+------------------------------           F(  1,    72) =  126.60
       Model |  1557.60578     1  1557.60578           Prob > F      =  0.0000
    Residual |  885.853676    72  12.3035233           R-squared     =  0.6375
-------------+------------------------------           Adj R-squared =  0.6324
       Total |  2443.45946    73  33.4720474           Root MSE      =  3.5076

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
    lnlength |  -38.44907   3.417211   -11.25   0.000    -45.26116   -31.63698
       _cons |   222.3488   17.87337    12.44   0.000     186.7189    257.9788
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The two estimates are fairly close.

Comment: +1 That's a clever approach.  Note that it works in the example because the SD of [length] is a small fraction of the mean (about $22.3/188 \approx 12\%$): logarithms of values $1+x$ in the range $1 \pm 2 SD \approx (0.75, 1.25)$ are very close to $x$ itself, whence the logarithm is approximately a linear function within this range.  When any one of the independent variables exhibits appreciably more relative variation than this, all bets are off.

Comment: That's a good way of putting it. For instance, with price and mpg, the ratio is 3.7, and the two effects are 850 dollars apart.